# How to calculate amp hours when voltage and amperage changes

Tags: batteries, load, lithium, capacity

I have a Lithium battery pack.  All I know about this battery is that its no-load voltage is exactly 20.0v when charged.  I then connect a load to this battery; I have no direct information about the load, however, the load is connected through a power tester circuit which shows the following information (recorded at the specified time intervals below):

Time (initial): 18.9v, 5.6A

Time (after 1 hr): 16.2v, 5.2A

Time (after another 16 minutes, or at 1.27 hr): 12.0v, 4.4A

**QUESTIONS:**

1. What is the AH rating of this battery?
2. Is a voltage drop of 1.1V significant?
3. How many watts is the load drawing?

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: We are not here to do your homework for you. Your questions 1 and 3 are just basic manipulations of the number you have shown. We can help you try to understand, but aren't just going to give you answers to purely mechanical questions so that you can avoid having to learn the theory.

Comment: Olin, this was a legitimate question and a legitimate request for assistance.  I'm not an engineer or a student, but more of a hobbyist asking for help. As can be seen from the responses below, there's about 3 different answers from 3 different engineers who already know the theory?  This was the place I thought to come and ask for help, but unfortunately your response has turned me off coming here again.  Thanks to the people that responded, particularly Tony Stewart.

Comment: Whether this is homework or not (no, we're not going to take your word for it, LOL) is irrelevant.  We don't just give answers to homework or homework-style questions here for good reason.  It is permissible to ask such questions, but then you have to show what you've tried and what exactly you're stuck on.  We can then teach you what you need to know so that *you* can get past it.  That's how this site works.  We don't do *gimme da anser*.  If you can't handle that, then you're right, you don't belong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Without knowing your pack model and chemistry, we have to make certain assumptions.

- **The 1C rate is std Ah rating 20hr constant current,CC down to 3V/cell.**
- This may be good for 500 charge cycles and good Ah rating, but
- you are using battery life quickly at 20 times this rate or 20C
- Both Ah rating and charge cycle life decrease with faster rates.
- initial voltage drops quick at first with any load
- then drop depends on the internal resistance or effective series res., ESR

  - ESR = ΔV / ΔA = Ω [Ohms] or differential slope of voltage and current
- given;

  > Voc=20V
  >   Time (initial): 18.9v, 5.6A
  >   Time (after 1 hr): 16.2v, 5.2A
  >   Time (after another 16 minutes, or at 1.27 hr): 12.0v, 4.4A
- Std. LiPo Voltage ( with some load)  =3.8V so 20/3.8V = 5.26 cells

  - rounding down we assume it is 5 in series or 5S
  - now we can normalize or curve-fit your performance with others
- Voc/5   = 4V
- V(t0)   = 18.9/5 = 3.78V  @5.6A,  P(t0) = 106 watts (18.9V*5.6A)
- V(1h)   = 16.2/5 = 3.24V  @5.2A,  P(1h) = 85 watts (16.2V*5.2A)
- V(1.27h) =12.0/5 = **2.40V**  @4.4A,  P(1.24h) = 29 watts (12*2.4)

  - **any less than 3V per cell accelerates cell death**
- it seems to fit a profile of <20C after 1 hr or slightly above blue curve.
- after 1h your V=3.24V/cell so from the curve your capacity remaining was ~5%

  - using power reduced to 26%, initial  watts, you got an extra 27% time.
- > Amp-hour [Ah] capacity "delivered" is simply the sum of current every
  >   minute averaged over time and minutes converted to hours.
- > This will be less than default 1C rating.
- > Watt-hour [Wh] capacity "delivered is Ah times Volts [V*Ah=Wh] every minute averaged and converted to hours.
- > Never go beyond knee of the curve and if you buy more packs and use only to 50 % discharge, and never go above 4.1V during charge, you can expect up to 5x the number of life cycles but less Wh capacity in each cycle.

Now you do the math.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond Tony, appreciate the detail.  Thanks to your response, I knew what to look for, and now have further information. You were right that it is a 5S pack, but furthermore it is 5S3P made of 15 Panasonic NCR18650B Lithium ion cells.  Each cell is meant to be 3400mAh (max), thus I should theoretically be getting 10.2ah from this pack, but it seems I am well short for some reason.  Considering it is a new pack, I am unable to determine why I am only getting half the power. Thx.

Comment: over or undercharging any cell can kill the pack. Can you measure differential ESR and cell voltage? or test it with Panasonic's test method? https://www.math.ubc.ca/~wetton/papers/NCR18650B.pdf

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to get an Ah rating, the battery that is being tested has to be drained down to 0 over the course of a specified amount of time.  The amount of amperage that it took to get it down to zero, over that specified amount of time constitutes the Ah rating. I think your battery is 20 Ah, you will need 4 hours with 5 A, 4h*5A=20Ah to discharge your battery.
2. you need to consider the load of your multimeter, so if this is in high impedance, 1.1 V it's ok.
3. Power disipation = V*A = 1.1 V * 5.6 A= 6.16 W

Comment: To specify your AHaverage, you need to estimate the VoltageAverage and the CurrentAverage. Measure the voltage in several steps of time and later make the average of all your measures. Do the same with the current.

Comment: you never discharge a battery to 0V. For a 20V battery discharging down to 16V is about the limit, so his battery is approximately 5.2Ah.

Comment: Discharging battery to 0V will dead your battery and it'll be almost useless after this situation.For every battery,there'll a discharge cut-off(for Li-ion it's ~3.3V).